# Digit sum of any number until sum is one-digit

Tags: python

How would I repeat the loop until the sum becomes a single-digit number? This is how far I got:

```
numb = "123456789"

for x in numb:
  sum += int(x)

print(sum)
```

Comment: Look up `while` and don't use `sum` as a variable name, as this is a built-in function.

Comment: It helps, thank you.

Though I do not know what this does:
    n = sum(map(int, str(n)))
care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
def sum_digits(integ):
        integ=int(integ)
        if integ <= 9:
            return integ
        res = sum(divmod(integ, 10)) 
        return sum_digits(res)
```

Comment: That is a recursive function, right? Still gotta look into those, but thank you.

Comment: Could be easily reformatted as while loop

Answer (score 1):

Try following snippet:

```
def sumdigi(num):
    sumi = 0
    for i in num:
       sumi+=int(i)
    if (sumi)>9:
        return sumdigi(str(sumi))
    return sumi

print(sumdigi("12345"))
```